# How can maintain some user settings as it is after app is updated with new version?

Tags: iphone

I want save user note which can not be remove if they update app version.

//http://iphoneworxx.com/sample-code-ios-iphone-and-ipad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data not stored in the application bundle is preserved during upgrades.

Since the Application bundle is read only on the device you are not able to store any data there. So you should be ok.

Comment: But there will be something so user can not lost there note if app is upgraded.

Comment: Yes all data not in the application bundle, which is data in the document, library, temp, ... directory will not be touched. Just the app bundle gets replaced when the user upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

Files can be saved into the Documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

And any object (including a few primitives) with [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefauls];
[userDefaults setObject:anObject forKey:@"ObjectKey"];
[userDefaults synchronize];

NSObject* anotherObject = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"ObjectKey"];
```